# MySQL Sorting Problem for an autocomplete

Tags: mysql, search, autocomplete, sql-order-by, sql-like

I have an autocomplete on my site where a user enters a class at their school.  It then provides a dropdown of Classes that have the words they entered somewhere in their fields.  The Classes table has the fields Class_ID, Term_ID, Department_Code, Course_Code, Class_Code, Course_Title, Instructor which are all searched by the terms the user puts in.  Suppose a use enters the words "international econ".  It would then search these two terms in the fields as follows:

```
SELECT Class_ID, Department_Code, Course_Code, Class_Code, Course_Title, Instructor FROM Classes AND ((REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT(Department_Code, Course_Code, Class_Code), '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', '') LIKE '%international%' OR Instructor LIKE '%international%' OR Course_Title LIKE '%international%') AND (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT(Department_Code, Course_Code, Class_Code), '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', '') LIKE '%econ%' OR Instructor LIKE '%econ%' OR Course_Title LIKE '%econ%')) LIMIT 10
```

Two quick notes on this query-- I do the REPLACE() and CONCAT() so that users can enter depts/courses/sections as a unit, e.g. ECON-101 (A dept and a course together).  Also, I've pasted a greatly simplified query which leaves out the way I currently sort and group.

However my question deals with how I can sort the results.  I want entries matching the Class_Code to be returned at the the top, followed by Course_Code, followed by Dept, then followed by Course_Title, lastly by prof.  In other words, I want the results sorted by the amount of specfificity the user provides in the autocomplete.  If they know the Class_Code, I'd therefore like it to be at the top.

I can't think of a way of doing this sort which doesn't require a huge query.  So far the only way I can think of doing it is aliasing a bunch of LIKE comparison for each term to each field, and then ORDERing by those aliases.  That's equivelant to 5 times the number of words the user enters in the autocomplete.. In other words, a huge ugly query.

Is there a simple, efficient way to do this sort? If there was something like an INSTR() function which took **multiple** strings to search for, I could easily just compare all the words in the autocomplete to each field, and always sort on the 5 aliases produced by that.

Any input welcome, even if it's a general suggestion that goes beyond the scope of the question.  However, in advance I want to note that I'm not open to using something like FULLTEXT or a search system like Sphinx here because I don't feel its fit for a non-intensive, fast query like this one.  Also, I'm not open to restructuring my database.  So I'd like to do this with a good MySQL query on what I already have.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the UNION operator? You could separate the different queries into their own SELECT statement, and then join them all together by using UNION. This will automatically keep them in the groups that you want them - that being the order in which you run the SELECT statements.

It may make your query bigger but should be effective.

Comment: It might turn out that the long way is the only way to do it.. if so I'm open to doing a big UNION or aliasing a bunch and ordering them.  Just posted to see if there's some efficient method I'm leaving out

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY accepts multiple values, so just list the columns in the order you want:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name(s) ASC|DESC
```

Another possibility you can try is to write an SQL generator function.  Sometimes if the script is very ugly and is bound to change, having a function generate the script in modular format can make it easier to see what is going on.

Comment: Did you read the question?  I dont want to sort on columns but on matches to columns.. And there are problems with doing that for all of them that I raise in the qstn

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
order by case when code  like '%blabla%' then 0 else 1 end
        ,case when dept  like '%blabla%' then 0 else 1 end
        ,case when title like '%blabla%' then 0 else 1 end
```

That way, all matches in code will sort before matches in dept, etc.

**Updated for comment**
If I understand the last comment correctly, your concerns are that you will be repeating complicated expressions in the query? In that case you could either wrap the replace/concat etc in a derived table (see below) or you can create a view.

```
select *
  from (select class_code
              ,department_code
              ,department_code
              ,replace(concat(...)) as code
              ,replace(concat(...)) as dept
              ,replace(concat(...)) as title
          from classes
         where class_code      like '%blabla%'
            or department_code like '%blabla%'
            or class_title     like '%blabla%'
       ) as wrapped
 order by case when code  like '%blabla%' then 0 else 1 end
         ,case when dept  like '%blabla%' then 0 else 1 end
         ,case when title like '%blabla%' then 0 else 1 end
```

Just be sure to do the actual search on the real columns rather then the computed columns to make sure mysql can use the indexes.

By the way, mysql doesn't care if the query is long and complicated as long as the filters and joins look "simple".

Comment: Yep.  I could see doing it this way (see my question for the idea of aliasing the terms).  Only thing is, its pretty long because the number of lines is 5 times the number of words the user enters

Comment: this also might work: `ORDER BY FIELD("blabla", code, dept, title)`
FIELD() docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field

Comment: @German, thanks for the reference. I did not know about the Field function. But it seems like it only support equality tests, and thus we cannot use it in OP's context?

Comment: Yes @Ronnis, you are right, this will not work here for partial matches. Didn't think it through